# Rails & Primary Keys / Uniqueness. How do you use multiple columns for a primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, primary-key, unique

My question is quite identical to this one ([multicolumn primary keys in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201572/multicolumn-primary-keys-in-rails)) but I'm still not understanding this 100%.

Let's say I have a model Visit

```
visits
    id
    room_id
    date
    created_at
    updated_at
```

In this case, I want (room_id, date) to be my 'primary key'. Now, this post is saying I don't need to change my primary key, jus add uniqueness validations and stuff?

So do I need

```
add_index :visits, [:room_id, :date]
```

or

```
add_index :visits, [:id, :room_id]
add_index :visits, [:id, :date]
```

? Do I tie each column I want to be in the 'primary key' to :id like the latter code, or do I just put my desired columns into []'s like the former code.

Also, how do I do the validations? I don't want either of :room_id or :date to be unique, only their combination. How do I do this in Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the previous question, the right one is:

```
add_index :visits, [:room_id, :date], :unique => true
```

This piece of code prevents the database from inserting a `room_id` with the same `date`. But in terms of model validation, you also need to add:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :date,    :scope => :room_id
```

This way, `ActiveRecord` can and will validate the record before trying to insert.

P.S.: Change the `date` column name to something more specific like `start_date`, `creation_date`, etc. I believe it could cause some potential problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks! One more question. What if there were 3 columns needed to make up a primary. a, b, and c. add_index :table [:a, :b, :c], unique: true would add the index. But about about the next part. validates_uniqueness_of :b, scope: :a, validate_uniqueness_of :c, scope: :a??

Comment: Well, that is sure a weird use case. I don't know about that, perhaps some array notation `validates_uniqueness_of :date, :scope => [:room_id, :another_id]`, but i don't know for sure.